# react native iOS Apollo - TypeError: Network request failed - URI accessible from outside the app

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I've got a graphql URI that I need to query from my react-native App. This URI is public and I've got access to its schema/structure when I simply type the URI in my browser.

As soon as I try to query it from my code, I get the [TypeError: Network request failed] error (logs are created in the function that builds my ApolloClient).

I've checked the URI a million time, it's the same as the one I put in my browser, and the one I've used in the past to successfully query the DB.

This is the client-building function:

```
export function initServices({
  uri,
  authToken,
  mockMeanDelay = 400,
  mock = false,
  mockScenarios = [],
}: Options): Services {
  let mockRemoteController = null;
  let linkToOutsideWorld: ApolloLink;
  const messageBus = createMessageBus();

    const terminatingLink = createUploadLink({
      uri: CORRECT_URI_HERE,
    })
    const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
      const token = await authToken();
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        },
      };
    });


    linkToOutsideWorld = from([authLink, withCustomScalars(), terminatingLink]);


  const errorReportingLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors)
      graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(
          `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
        ),
      );
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    if (networkError) console.error(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
  });

  const link = ApolloLink.from([errorReportingLink, linkToOutsideWorld]);

  const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
    // @ts-ignore
    introspectionQueryResultData: introspectionResult,
  });

  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        // We prefer using a `cache-and-network` policy so that screens
        // are always in sync with backend
        // Otherwise, the default policy would not fetch the server
        // data from server if the result of query is already in cache
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      },
    },
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      cacheRedirects: {
        Query: {
          // @ts-ignore issue in typing of cacheRedirects
          userById: (_, { userId }: QueryUserByIdArgs, { getCacheKey }) =>
            getCacheKey({ __typename: 'User', id: userId }),
          // @ts-ignore  issue in typing of cacheRedirects
          gatheringSpaceById: (
            _,
            { gatheringSpaceId }: QueryGatheringSpaceByIdArgs,
            { getCacheKey },
          ) =>
            getCacheKey({
              __typename: 'GatheringSpace',
              id: gatheringSpaceId,
            }),
          // @ts-ignore  issue in typing of cacheRedirects
          gatheringInstanceById: (
            _,
            { gatheringInstanceId }: QueryGatheringInstanceByIdArgs,
            { getCacheKey },
          ) =>
            getCacheKey({
              __typename: 'GatheringInstance',
              id: gatheringInstanceId,
            }),
        },
      },
      fragmentMatcher,
    }),
  });

  return { apolloClient, messageBus, mockRemoteController };
}
```

When I replace the URI with another publicly available one, it seems to work so my guess is that there's an issue with the back-end side. But how is it possible that I have full access to the schema and queries with my browser?
Any tips to help debugging are welcome too!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is likely with your auth. Try doing an unauthenticated query from your R-N client first. How is your client getting the `authenticationToken` from the server? (If it's generating it locally that's going to be hackable or is that just a mock?)

Comment: It was a certification issue (it had expired), indeed. Thanks for your comment @MichelFloyd. I have a hard time understanding how a certification is needed when the URL is accessible for anyone to query directly. Anyway it's now working. Thanks!

Comment: If you're connecting with https then the certificate should be valid even if you're not authenticated. Perhaps the direct access was http?

Comment: It was https. But now that you mention it, I remember that it was crossed and in red in my browser. This was a pretty clear hint I should have picked up 